# FileNet domain creation was successful, but still not able to find the directory configuration after login to FileNet ACCE

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, openshift, filenet

Issue:
FileNet domain creation was successful, but still not able to find the directory configuration after login to FileNet ACCE through default admin account. This admin account was created/used during the FNCPE deployment stage.

```
Error Stack trace:
The below error occurs while creating the directory configuration from FileNet ACCE ,Updating SSL Settings for FileNet Content Manager on OpenShift
{"@timestamp":"2024-02-15T14:00:47.383Z","@metadata":{"beat":"filebeat","type":"_doc","version":"7.17.3"},"log":{"offset":163781,"file":{"path":"/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/fncmdeploy-cpe-deploy-555f89b445-vfqnm/messages.log"}},"input":{"type":"log"},"log-type":"application","app_id":"CPE_5511_000","ecs":{"version":"1.12.0"},"host":{"name":"fncmdeploy-cpe-deploy-555f89b445-vfqnm"},"agent":{"type":"filebeat","version":"7.17.3","hostname":"fncmdeploy-cpe-deploy-555f89b445-vfqnm","ephemeral_id":"6a38ce91-d03e-429a-9ef8-b74ee643dead","id":"fbf3137a-8283-4da9-8b34-c5be76ec3164","name":"fncmdeploy-cpe-deploy-555f89b445-vfqnm"},"message":"[2/15/24, 14:00:41:722 UTC] 0000013c com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager        E CWPKI0824E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  Host name verification error while connecting to host [10.212.225.217].  The host name used to access the server does not match the server certificate's SubjectDN or Subject Alternative Name information.  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: [No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.212.225.217 found]."}
```

AWS OpenShift ROSA POC work is being carried out. Until this point, following activities have been completed

- OpenShift Cluster creation
- PostGreSQL database setup, S3 storage
- Bastion Server setup
- Connectivity from organization to OpenShift Cluster through Bastion Server
- FileNet software (FNCPE) deployment at OpenShift Cluster
- FileNet Domain Creation (along with Organization On-Prem MS AD connectivity)

Exception is to get the FileNet running and perform all doc operations.